# Is there a way to kick off all tests?

Tags: bazel

I'm not very familiar with Bazel, other than having to add or remove a few things from `BUILD` here and there and knowing how to execute the tests in a certain directory.

I'm currently working in a code base that has unit tests scattered throughout subdirectories, but they're all within that subdirectory's `BUILD`. Is there a way to kick off all the tests?

Answer (score 3):

You can run all tests via:

```
bazel test //...
```

Maybe you need some config to run your test (see `.bazelrc`)

```
bazel --config=my_config //...
```

Similar you can build your complete workspace via:

```
bazel build //...
```

Comment: I will try this when I get the chance. Somewhat non-related, but what is the `//` used for? I've always used this but never know why

Comment: All target patterns starting with // are resolved relative to the current workspace. More explanation here: https://bazel.build/run/build#specifying-build-targets

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the ["Building multiple targets" section](https://bazel.build/run/build#specifying-build-targets) in the Bazel target reference. In particular, you are likely looking for invocations like `bazel test //subdir:all` or `bazel test //subdir/...`.